# CV template run time error in TeXstudio

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, texstudio, friggeri-cv

i am trying to make cv by using LaTex template but there is an error when i start compilation.

```
Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex" The fontspec package requires either    XeTeX or LuaTeX to function. You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex". For immediate help type H <return>.
```

i have compiled this template with XeTex and LualaTex `tools->commands->XeTex/LualaTex` but error exists. I think there is some error in fonts package because when i compile with `Xelatex` it shows following error

```
Font EU1/HelveticaNeueUltraLight(0)/m/n/14="Helvetica Neue UltraLight:" at 14.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. \header{john}{smith}{junior business analyst}
```

These errors show up in every cv template when i run, it would be helpful if someone guides me how to fix this and editor i am using is TexStudio.

Comment: I rather looks like you don't have the font HelveticaNeueUltraLight installed

Comment: it is related to `fontspec.sty` package but in template i have included this package by `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad can you add your minimal working example !

Comment: @SayOL please goto following link and download the file its the full template and example i am working on `http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv`

Comment: Substitute helvetica with the fonts you actually have.

Answer (score 1):

The example file  of the template needs to be compiled with eitehr XeLateX or LuaLaTeX. Be careful to use fonts you actually have available on your machine.